Sorting expressions with Sqrt
I get an unexpected output when I do
SortBy[{{Sqrt[2/7], 4/7}, {Sqrt[3/7], 5/7}, {Sqrt[2/3], 5/6}, {1/Sqrt[7], 1/2}, 
        {1/Sqrt[3], 2/3}, {1/Sqrt[2], 1}}, First]
(* {{Sqrt[2/7], 4/7}, {Sqrt[3/7], 5/7}, {Sqrt[2/3], 5/6}, {1/Sqrt[2], 1},
    {1/Sqrt[3], 2/3}, {1/Sqrt[7], 1/2}} *)

in Mathematica 12.2 and 13.3. I would expect them to be ordered by numerical value. Can you please try the newer and older versions? It is related but not precisely elaborated in other questions/answers.

It is not a bug. Try SortBy[..., N@*First].

Not a bug, but definitely not what you might expect. Look at the full form for Sqrt[2/7] and 1/Sqrt[7] to see why they get sorted differently.  Try SortBy[..., Composition[N, First]] to make sure you are comparing numerical values and not the expression itself

Sort[(...),  First[#1] < First[#2] &] works well without the need to convert to real numbers.

SortBy[(...), First, Less] also works well.

I do not understand why Sort[(...),  #1[[1]] < #2[[1]] &] and SortBy[(...), First, Less] and SortBy[(...), First] are not equivalent.

You can use SortBy, with the NumericalOrder as 3rd argument:
lst = {{Sqrt[2/7], 4/7}, {Sqrt[3/7], 5/7}, {Sqrt[2/3], 5/6}, {1/Sqrt[7], 1/2}, {1/Sqrt[3], 2/3}, {1/Sqrt[2], 1}};    
SortBy[lst, First, NumericalOrder]

This will also work for complex numbers, whereas Less or First[#1] < First[#2] & (as suggested above) will not work for such cases.

FYI this doesn't work in 11.2 even though NumericalOrder was introduced in 11.1

Mathematica is sorting according to the FullForm of the input expression. If you want it sorted by numerical value then numericise first with N.  For example Sort[N[{1/Sqrt[3], 1/Sqrt[7]}]] sorts numerically, whereas N[Sort[{1/Sqrt[3], 1/Sqrt[7]}]] sorts according to the full form of {1/Sqrt[3], 1/Sqrt[7]} which is List[Power[3,Rational[-1,2]],Power[7,Rational[-1,2]]].
If you want the original input form sorted you could do this:
inputlist = {{Sqrt[2/7], 4/7}, {Sqrt[3/7], 5/7}, {Sqrt[2/3], 
5/6}, {1/Sqrt[7], 1/2}, {1/Sqrt[3], 2/3}, {1/Sqrt[2], 1}};

input2 = {N[#1], #1, #2} & @@@ inputlist;

sorted = Rest /@ SortBy[input2, First]


{{1/Sqrt[7], 1/2}, {Sqrt[2/7], 4/7}, {1/Sqrt[3], 2/3}, {Sqrt[3/7], 5/
7}, {1/Sqrt[2], 1}, {Sqrt[2/3], 5/6}}

N[sorted]


{{0.377964, 0.5}, {0.534522, 0.571429}, {0.57735,
0.666667}, {0.654654, 0.714286}, {0.707107, 1.}, {0.816497,
0.833333}}

